# running maven project in eclipse luna

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I have installed everything and I am using eclipse luna ..I am trying to run this project "sample" but no luck so far https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment..I have installed everything and using eclipse luna but its giving me android v4 compatibility error ..Please help me

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sample: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.github.devnied.emvnfccard:sample:apk:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find android.support:compatibility-v4:jar:20.0.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

its pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>EMV NFC android paycard reader</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.github.devnied.emvnfccard</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
      <version>20.0.0-rc1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.devnied.emvnfccard</groupId>
            <artifactId>library</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <artifactId>crouton</artifactId>
            <groupId>de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget</groupId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
                    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
       <executions>
        <execution>
         <phase>test</phase>
         <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
          <mainClass>my.company.name.packageName.TestMain</mainClass>
          <arguments>
           <argument>myArg1</argument>
           <argument>myArg2</argument>
          </arguments>
         </configuration>
        </execution>
       </executions>
      </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: In Central you will not find any SNAPSHOT version.

Comment: so what's the solution? please help

Answer (score 0):

Use released version instead of SNAPSHOT:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.devnied.emvnfccard</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Or add repository containing SNAPSHOT version of this library (if you must use 1.1.1-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: how could I add the repository containing snapshot version.please guide mee.

Comment: To add repository check this documentation [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html), but it is possible that there is no one with this library. Check documentation, and maybe [this](https://github.com/devnied/EMV-NFC-Paycard-Enrollment/releases) will be helpfull.
You can always build this version by your self - it is open source.